# react-hot-toast is rerendering multiple times I believe

Tags: accessibility, remix.run

I am a blind web developer attempting to build a simple todo app in remix. It is working, but I'd like ot provide accessible notifications when a todo was added successfullly. Currently when I add a todo the alert gets repeated 8 times and I'm not sure why. I am using role of status, which is only supposed to announce when content changes, but with nvda and chrome it is announcing all 8 times the exact same message. Does anyone have any insite? Here is my todo app action/loader/component.

```
import toast, { Toaster, resolveValue } from "react-hot-toast";
import { json, redirect } from "@remix-run/node";
import type {
  ActionArgs,
  ActionFunction,
  LoaderFunction,
} from "@remix-run/node";
import {
  Form,
  useActionData,
  useLoaderData,
  useNavigate,
  useNavigation,
  useSearchParams,
} from "@remix-run/react";
import { db } from "~/utils/db";
import type { todo } from "~/types/todo";
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";

export const loader: LoaderFunction = async () => {
  const data = await db.todo.findMany();
  return json(data);
};

export const action: ActionFunction = async ({ request }: ActionArgs) => {
  const data = await request.formData();
  const name = data.get("name");
  console.log(`name=${name}`);
  const complete = data.get("complete") === null ? false : true;
  console.log(complete);
  const description = data.get("description");
  if (
    typeof description !== "string" ||
    typeof name !== "string" ||
    typeof complete !== "boolean"
  ) {
    throw new Error("Form was not submitted Correctly");
  }
  await db.todo.create({ data: { name, description, complete } });
  return json({ msg: "Your form was submitted successfully." });
};
export default function Index() {
  const data = useLoaderData<todo[]>();
  const nav = useNavigation();

  const { msg } = useActionData() || "";

  toast(msg);

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>todo app</h1>
      <br />

      <ul>
        {data.map((d) => {
          return (
            <li key={d.id}>
              name:{d.name}
              <br />
              description:{d.description}
              <br />
              Complete{" "}
              <input type="checkbox" disabled={true} checked={d.complete} />
            </li>
          );
        })}
      </ul>
      <br />
      <h2>add</h2>
      <Form method="post">
        <label htmlFor="name">Name:</label>{" "}
        <input type="text" id="name" name="name" />
        <br />
        <label htmlFor="description">Description:</label>{" "}
        <textarea rows={5} id="description" name="description" />
        <br />
        <label htmlFor="complete">Complete</label>
        <input type="checkbox" id="complete" name="complete" />
        <button type="submit" disabled={nav.state !== "idle"}>
          Add
        </button>
      </Form>
    </div>
  );
}
```

and here is my route.tsx fjile with the toaster in it.

```
import { Toaster, resolveValue } from "react-hot-toast";
import { cssBundleHref } from "@remix-run/css-bundle";
import type { LinksFunction } from "@remix-run/node";
import {
  Links,
  LiveReload,
  Meta,
  Outlet,
  Scripts,
  ScrollRestoration,
} from "@remix-run/react";

export const links: LinksFunction = () => [
  ...(cssBundleHref ? [{ rel: "stylesheet", href: cssBundleHref }] : []),
];

export default function App() {
  return (
    <html lang="en">
      <head>
        <meta charSet="utf-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1" />
        <Meta />
        <Links />
      </head>
      <body>
        <Outlet />
        <div role="status">
          <Toaster></Toaster>
        </div>
        <ScrollRestoration />
        <Scripts />
        <LiveReload />
      </body>
    </html>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Remix will re-render your route component multiple times as it transitions from idle to submitting to revalidation.

Have you tried wrapping the `toast` call inside a `useEffect` with `msg` as a dependency?